# How can I find inverse independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a method for finding inverse independent vectors of a matrix transform? by inverse independent vector I mean:
$$
Mx=M^{-1}x
$$
where $M$ is an $n \times n$ invertible matrix and $x$ is an $\Bbb R^n$ vector.

Comment: Do you mean find $x$ such that $Mx=M^{-1}x$?

Comment: Yes, but if possible, find all solutions of x

Comment: $x \in \ker \{M^2 -I\}$.

Comment: There are no invertible $\;m\times n\;,\;\;m\neq n\;$ , matrices...

Comment: Yeah I realized my mistake after I wrote the question, but I figure anyone who can answer the question knows that $m \equiv n$ so I think it may be better to leave question in the original state. However if you feel differently, go ahead and edit it. (assuming you have edit privileges)

Comment: @AlexSilva, can you show the steps involved in your solution?

Comment: @JDOdle $Mx = M^{-1}x \implies M^2x = Ix \implies (M^2 - I)x = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
Mx = M^{-1}x \implies\\
M^2 x = x \implies\\
M^2x - Ix  = 0\implies\\
(M^2 - I)x = 0
$$
So, $x$ is "inverse independent" iff $x$ is in the kernel of $M^2 - I$.

---

A further observation is that we may rewrite the equation as $(M-I)(M+I)x = 0$.  This allows us to state that $x$ is "inverse independent" iff it lies in the direct sum of the eigenspaces associated with $\pm 1$.